# Is there a Visual Studio add-in for populating resource files from strings in a code file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, localization

I'm maintaining a WinForms application which was not written using any development patters conducive to localizing the classes in the project which were not directly associated with forms, or the code-behind partials of the forms.

Thus, there is MessageBox() code with English text in it in almost every code file. I'd like to find a tool which will "scrape" those strings from the code, insert the strings in a resource file, and substitute a call to the resource with the substituted string in a comment.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: I know that Resharper supports this, or something very similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [ReSharper 5 Internationalization](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Move_Strings_to_Resource_Files) Features

> When ReSharper finds a localizable
>   string, it helps you move it to a
>   resource file with only a couple of
>   clicks. You can optionally search for
>   identical strings and refactor them to
>   use the new resource item.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I installed Resharper 5, and there is no such feature listed when the cursor is over a string.

Comment: Found the feature, but it's not everything I was looking for. Even so after an hour or so of scanning code files I got everything into the resource file, so I guess I should call it an appropriate tool!

Answer (score 5):

The [Visual Localizer](http://visuallocalizer.codeplex.com) projects focuses on this very issue and is free.

Comment: The given link is no longer working.

Answer (score 2):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do it. There is a Resharper plugin called [RGreatEx](http://sharptoolbox.com/tools/rgreatex) that has a lot of localization refactorings for strings. I'm guessing you are looking for something free though, and both of these cost money. RGreatEx also hasn't seen updates in more than two years.

EDIT: Did some more searching, and found [this tool](http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. It doesn't supporting pulling strings into resources, but it does have side-by-side editing of multiple resource files to ease writing string translations.

Comment: No; I'm willing to spend money. Although, I do have a certificate for Telerik's competing product. And, I'd rather keep this particular codebase in VS2005, where it's very well-behaved, unless there are some good arguments for going to VS2008 this is all in maintenance mode. For this codebase, VS2010 is still too much of a different animal...

Comment: @Rob: are you aware that you can use VS2010 and target .NET 2.0?

Comment: @John I'm aware of that, but there are other ancillary tools on the VM with this code, and I just don't want to move it all.

Comment: RGreatEx is discontinued, but some of the features are in resharper 6

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper is of course the best in this field, as it can scan all strings in your code base and let you know which can be placed into resources.

But if you intend to use a free tool, Microsoft does have an open source one here,

http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/

You have to manually scan all files using this tool as it is not as smart as ReSharper.

Answer (score -4):

You can also use [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to do this kind of thing. They're built into Vis Studio as of 2005 I think.

Comment: -1: I know T4 templates, and I don't see how they apply to this. Explain and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: point being - you should explain how T4 Templates solve this problem. Then, if you want me to leave the downvote, I'll leave it.